# From my understanding block formatting contexts cant overlap, so why does absolutely positioned elements overlap?

Tags: css

From my understanding when you create an absolutely positioned element, it creates a new block formatting context. New block formatting elements cant overlap from my understanding. Am I not understanding block formatting contexts or am is absolutely positioned elements an abnormality to that overlapping rule?

```
<div></div>
<div></div>

<style>
    div {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 10px;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no rule I know of that block level elements can't overlap.

In the regular document flow, few, if any, elements of any kind (in line, block or otherwise) overlap. When you start working with positioning, floats, negative margins etc. block elements start overlapping just as much as inline elements.

Comment: thanks for the reply but block elements are different from, block formatting contexts. 
https://www.fuseinteractive.ca/blog/understanding-humble-clearfix#.V6H_p2Wof6s  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context